# Which font is similar to Christopher Wool's Stencil?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation

His stencil: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/338192253239825468/

the closest thing i found is: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jnlevine/narrow-stencil/

but it's too narrow.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that this may not actually be a font? On close inspection, the edges of the letters are extremely rough and irregular suggesting that it might have been created using a real stencil, possibly even hand cut.

Comment: yes it is a stencil .. clearly. but im still looking for a digital font that is the closest to it. thanks

Comment: I've added an answer now

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is probably an ordinary font that has been hand cut to make a stencil, and then used to paint the letters onto a substrate since it has very rough edges.

As a starting point, you could search for monospace sans serif fonts.  One that appears to be quite similar is [Monofonto](https://www.fonts.com/font/typodermic/monofonto).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Kane Display Stencil](https://t-wo.it/font/kane-display/) looks close

Comment: not really... gaps on all letters are different. The only similarity is that it is a stencil font.

Comment: so far it is the closest digital font i;ve seen to this. unless one can find a better one. thanks @mike